# How can I debug a SQL connection in Java

Tags: java, sqlconnection

In my website I need to connect to a database. But I can't, it doesn't work, when I do

```
try {
    connexion = DriverManager.getConnection(url, name, password);
} catch (SQLException sqlex) {
    System.err.println("Connexion impossible - LoginServlet");
}
```

When I print `connexion`, it returns me `null`

```
System.out.println(connexion);
```

The url, name and password are valid cause I use them in an other application. So where the problem can come from ?

**EDIT**

```
url = jdbc:sqlserver://trixsql03;databaseName=TrixnetDev;
```

And I'm using Miscrosoft SQL Server

Comment: try to dump sqlex in the catch block.

Comment: Do you get an exception? **System.err.println("Connexion impossible - LoginServlet")** gets printed? and how do you print connexion, can you show us that bit of code too?

Comment: in catch block, do `sqlex.printStackTrace()` and show us the message. Also, show us the URL, maybe the URL syntax is wrong.

Comment: @Raf No exception, and **System.err.println("Connexion impossible - LoginServlet")** isn't printed

Comment: And what do you mean by when I print connexion?

Comment: @JamesWierzba Thanks, I don't know why but I see the error now. `No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver`

Comment: @SimonM. Please post the text value of `url` and also, is this microsoft sql server you are using?

Comment: @JamesWierzba Edited the question

Answer (score 0):

Looks connection object not created. There could be some Exception like Driver class not loaded.

Try to catch Exception along with SQLException. You should see the real issue.

```
try {
connexion = DriverManager.getConnection(url, name, password);
} catch (SQLException sqlex) {
  System.err.println("Connexion impossible - LoginServlet"+sqlex);
}catch (Exception sqlex) {
  System.out.println("Connexion impossible - LoginServlet"+sqlex);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you load the sql driver class? Which type of database is it? Using sql-server for example, it would be:

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
try {
    connexion = DriverManager.getConnection(url, name, password);
} catch (SQLException sqlex) {
    System.err.println("Connexion impossible - LoginServlet");
}
```

Comment: Yes I load the driver class